# Operation of Terminator operator in printf

Tags: c

consider the following snippet

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello, world
          ");
    return 0;
}
```

i read this in a book
The book says "printf never supplies new line automatically, so several calls may be used to build up an output line in stages". What does it mean????
Error is missing terminating operator

Comment: It means you should read a better book. There is no "terminating(/-or) operator" in C. What do **you** mean?

Comment: The quote isn't wrong, so I wouldn't necessarily put the book at fault here.

Comment: It means that you can use multiple printf statements to print the text of a single line. Which has no relation whatsoever to the invalid code you posted. Is this code a copy/paste from the book?

Comment: @SBI: If you addressed my, please reference correctly. I did not write it is wrong. It is just badly phrased.

Comment: I beleive you could use the line continuation operator (\\) to make that work.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp There is no such thing. You can however write one string literal on multiple lines in C, by surrounding each part of the sub strings with `" "`. They will then be automatically concatenated as if you had written them on a single line as `"hello" "world"`. Still, this has nothing to do with printf.

Comment: @Lundin I meant like [this](http://ideone.com/hnoVEW).

Comment: Wrote this from the book "The C Programming Language" by Dennis M. Ritchie

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Ok you edited your comment as I posted mine. Anyway, there's never a reason to use `\` for anything but macros.

Comment: @Lundin Ok. Yes, I was having issues getting the backslash to print.

Comment: @VarunSaproo Ok so from that book you can read that this code will cause a compiler error, which it indeed does. The book explains why. Turn the page from page 10 to page 11. And then follows an example with multiple printf statements, which will work. We really can't read the book for you, you have to do that yourself.

Comment: As a side note, that book is terribly old and in my opinion a very bad book for any purpose, but especially for learning C.

Comment: Which book u prefer???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"printf never supplies new line automatically, so several calls may be used to build up an output line in stages"*

This means that a newline `\n` is not inserted automatically after a `printf()` call. Meaning

```
printf("Hello");
printf("World");
```

Would print

```
HelloWorld
```

Even though it is printed in 2 different, `printf()`. A newline won't occur when one `printf()` has executed.

So, you can use multiple `printf()` to print the text in a single line.

---

If you want a newline `\n` between `printf()`, you need to supply that explicitly, like

```
printf("Hello\n");
printf("World");
```

Would print

```
Hello
World
```

---

Comment: If the OP could be arsed to just turn the page of their book, K&R (p11) gives a nearly identical example as you do here...

Comment: @Lundin, i have read that book, but i would say i didn't remember that. May be my sub conscious memory is playing tricks here. :)

Answer (score 0):

your  code is wrong for **printf()** function. You wrote printf function terminating character(") in second line. That's why you got termination character error after compile. It will be same line.

like this:

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello, world");
    return 0;
}
```

if you want to add new line you can add **\n** in printf.

like this:

```
printf("Hello, world\n");
```

Comment: Let me know if you don't understand.